# The Sound of Hydrogen using the NIST Spectral Database

Tags: audio, wolfram-mathematica, physics

In the video [The Sound of Hydrogen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhvW8yZdE5A) (original [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyi5SvPlMXc)), the sound
 is created using the NIST Atomic Spectra Database and then importing this edited data into Mathematica to modulate a Sine Wave.  I was wondering how he turned the data from the website into the values shown in the video ([3:47 - top of the page](http://youtu.be/IhvW8yZdE5A?t=3m47s)) because it is nothing like what is initially seen on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's different because in the tutorial the sampling rate is 8 kHz while it's probably higher in the original video.

---

Long answer:

I wish you'd asked this on http://physics.stackexchange.com or http://math.stackexchange.com instead so I could use formulae... Use the bookmarklet

```
javascript:(function(){function%20a(a){var%20b=a.createElement('script'),c;b.src='https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js',b.type='text/javascript',c='MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax:{inlineMath:[[\'$\',\'$\']],displayMath:[[\'\\\\[\',\'\\\\]\']],processEscapes:true}});MathJax.Hub.Startup.onload();',window.opera?b.innerHTML=c:b.text=c,a.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(b)}function%20b(b){b.MathJax===undefined?a(b.document):b.MathJax.Hub.Queue(new%20b.Array('Typeset',b.MathJax.Hub))}var%20c=document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),d,e;b(window);for(d=0;d<c.length;d++)e=c[d].contentWindow||c[d].contentDocument,e.document||(e=e.parentNode),b(e)})()
```

to render the formulae with MathJax:

First of all, note how the [Rydberg formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula#Rydberg_formula_for_hydrogen) provides the resonance frequencies of hydrogen as $\nu_{nm} = c R \left(\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{m^2}\right)$ where $c$ is the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) and $R$ the [Rydberg constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_constant). The highest frequency is $\nu_{1\infty}\approx 3000$ THz while for $n,m\to\infty$ there is basically no lower limit, though if you restrict yourself to the [Lyman series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_series) ($n=1$) and the [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series) ($n=2$), the lower limit is $\nu_{23}\approx 400$ THz. These are electromagnetic frequencies corresponding to light (not entirely in the [visual spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum) (ranging from 430–790 THz), there's some IR and lots of UV in there which you cannot see). "minutephysics" now simply considers these frequencies as sound frequencies that are remapped to the [human hearing range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing#Frequency_range) (ca 20-20000 Hz).

But as the video stated, not all these frequencies resonate with the same strength, and the data at http://nist.gov/pml/data/asd.cfm also includes the amplitudes. For the frequency $\nu_{nm}$ let's call the intensity $I_{nm}$ (intensity is amplitude squared, I wonder if the video treated that correctly). Then your signal is simply

$f(t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \sum\limits_{m=n+1}^M I_{nm}\sin(\alpha(\nu_{nm})t+\phi_{nm})$

where $\alpha$ denotes the frequency rescaling (probably something linear like $\alpha(\nu) = (20 + (\nu-400\cdot10^{12})\cdot\frac{20000-20}{(3000-400)\cdot 10^{12}})$ Hz) and the optional phase $\phi_{nm}$ is probably equal to zero.

Why does it sound slightly different? Probably the actual video did use a higher sampling rate than the 8 kHz used in the tutorial video.

Comment: Tobias, we also have MathJax support on [Mathematica.SE] which is where this question should have been to begin with.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good point, though my answer is taking a physics approach (admittedly I missed the part asking for obtaining the data and converting it...) Anyway it's silly that a question cannot be migrated after a mere six months.